# Can we add a certain binary row to a matrix which preserves total unimodularity?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, network-flow, totally-unimodular

Suppose I have a matrix $A\in \{-1, 0, 1\}^{m\times n}$ which is Totally Unimodular (TU), and a vector $b^T \in \{-1, 0, 1\}^{1\times n}$ which has exactly one entry which is $1$ and exactly one entry which is $-1$, and the rest of its entries are $0$.
If I add $b^T$ to $A$ to get the following matrix:
\begin{align*}
C =
\begin{bmatrix}
A \\
b^T
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Will $C$ be TU as well? I believe it should be, but I am having difficulty proving it. I tried working directly from the determinant definition of Total Unimodularity, but to no success

Comment: Is $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ or $b \in \{-1,0,1\}^n$?

Comment: @graphtheory123, do you see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/427709/595412) or [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/37589/517935) links?

Comment: @A.Omidi Yes I have seen those links

Comment: @joni I have updated my question to reflect the details of my scenario. Somehow I forgot to add the crucial detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conjecture is wrong as the following counterexample demonstrates. Consider

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

and

$$
b^\top = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then,

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

is **not** totally unimodular since $\det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \notin \{-1, 0, 1\}$.